# Javascript onclick form validation

Tags: javascript, validation, onclick

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong over here.. Its printing out alert when I put character like abc but when I have valid number its not saving...

```
function ValidateNumeric() {
    var val = document.getElementById("tbNumber").value;
    var validChars = '0123456789.'; 

    for(var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) { 
      if(validChars.indexOf(val.charAt(i)) == -1)
       alert('Please enter valid number');
       return false; 
        } 

        return true; 
    }

<INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT NAME="action" VALUE="Save Changes" onclick="return ValidateNumeric();" >
```

Comment: i think you should return the number in case true

Answer (score 6):

Pay attention to the statement start and end - the "return false;" will terminate the "for" loop on the first iteration.

Correct code:

```
function ValidateNumeric() {
  var val = document.getElementById("tbNumber").value;
  var validChars = '0123456789.'; 

  for(var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) { 
    if(validChars.indexOf(val.charAt(i)) == -1) {
      alert('Please enter valid number');
      return false;
    }
  } 

  return true; 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

format your `if` correctly, else it will consider only first statement.

```
 for(var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) { 
      if(validChars.indexOf(val.charAt(i)) == -1)
       {
        alert('Please enter valid number');
        return false; 
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use regular expressions!

```
function validateNumeric() {
    var val = document.getElementById("tbNumber").value;
    var regex = /^[0-9\.]+$/;

    if(regex.test(value))
        return true
    else {
        alert("Please enter a valid number");
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, that regex allows `1.22.3.6...2` as an input, which is probably not desired. You probably want to have the regex  [`^(\d+(\.\d+)?|\.\d+)$`](http://strfriend.com/vis?re=%5E%28%5Cd%2B%28%5C.%5Cd%2B%29%3F|%5C.%5Cd%2B%29%24)

Also, HTML tags should be lower case, and attributes should be quoted:

```
<input type="number" id="tbNumber" />
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Save Changes" onclick="return validateNumeric();"  />
```

Comment: +1 for a better solution, even if it does not address the root cause of the issue.